Book series where soldiers or pilots from Earth are teleported to a world where they learn how to use crystal magic technology
I read a series as a kid about a group of soldiers/pilots who were teleported to a different world where they had to learn how to use the crystal magic technology to fight off a great invasion. They had belts with flying crystals and shielding crystals, and hand weapons with shooting crystals, and communication crystals.
I think it was a trilogy or five books at most. I can't find it, or anything about it on the internet.

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you read/watched the work and what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

This is the Crystal duology by William R. Forstchen and Greg Morrison.

Book 1: The Crystal Warriors (1988)
Book 2: The Crystal Sorcerers (1991)

According to the plot summary on the Worlds Without End page for the first book, an American and Japanese soldier from WWII are summoned through a portal to the world of Haven, where they must unite and learn to use magic crystals as weapons in order to survive.

Summoned through a sorcerer's portal to faraway Haven, U.S. Captain Mark Phillips and Captain Ikawa Yoshio of the Japanese Imperial Army face powers far beyond what they knew in World War II. Sworn enemies, they must unite to survive. Their latent magical talents are discovered as they trade their primitive rifles and grenades for the crystals that focus their awesome killing energies. And the war is on, a war with vast rewards for the victors.

A Goodreads user review notes that the world of Haven is ruled by demigods and demons.

An action-filled portal fantasy in which opposing squads of US and Japanese soldiers from WWII must unite to survive in a feudal world ruled by demigods and demons.

The following excerpt from the first book mentions several different types of crystal worn on the belt and wristbands, including blast crystals, shield crystals and communication crystals.

"To return to our subject: You will find your blast crystals have the improved spirel cut, and your shield crystals have the standard brilliant cut. These offer far more refinement than the ones you used in training."
"We will also give you belts with other standard crystals, including communications, creativity, farseeing, healing, and others. Please take your old basic defensive crystal and put it in one of the slots on your belt. Your new shield crystal goes in the wristband on your left hand." He started to pass out the belts and wristbands.
Jeen spoke up. "I suggest you ignore all but the offensive, defensive, and communications crystals for now. Those are the ones that will save your life. Now, out to the courtyard for some quick practice before we go!"



YES!!! Thank you! It’s been driving me crazy for years! I’m gonna go see if I can track it down!

@Dracorvid - If this answer is correct, please consider marking it as accepted by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons near the top-left corner of the answer. It's this site's way of formally indicating that a query has been solved to the querent's satisfaction.

I'd try to track this book series down but, to be honest, just reading this answer has kind of made the word "crystals" lose all meaning for me.
